# Is the word 'perform' idiomatic in this context?

Tags: idiomatic-language, word-in-context

If my friend told me that he ordered online, a service of blood tests (made by a nurse) and he has one month that this purchase is valid from the time he paid for it, then he asked me when to **perform/do** it, while I think it's better to **do/perform** it tomorrow. I want to tell him that I recommend him to **do/perform** it tomorrow.

> I recommend you to **do**/**perform** it tomorrow.

To 'perform' means, in this case, to take his own blood sample, or it isn't necessary, and it can be said also when it's made by others as well?

Comment: Just use the most common verb *(**do**)*, and spend more time looking at getting ***basic syntax*** right rather than trying to prematurely extend your ***vocabulary***. There are many much more basic errors in your text here than the trivial issue of choosing a less common ***but still perfectly valid*** verb.

Comment: (You can ***do it, take it, perform it, get on with it, carry it out,...*** - it doesn't really make much difference.)

Comment: If my friend tells me he has bought an online blood test which is valid for a month, and asks me when he should do it, how do I say, "I recommend you do it tomorrow"? **Is he really doing it himself?**

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you for the recommendation. I looked at this test and seemed to me as if I didn't really; it was really full of mistakes, so I absolutely understand your feedback. I've just edited it, and I hope to not cause shame to myself again:) It seems I wrote in a moment I wasn't that concentrated.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came across as a bit harsh. I sometimes forget that for non-native speakers, it can be very difficult to simultaneously explain the nature of a problem ***and*** get all of the syntax right in the question text itself, when you're having to do both of those things in a foreign language! Note that in English we don't say ***take blood to himself*** - but we might say something like ***take his own blood sample***

Comment: Thanks for your words. If you didn't that English say "take his own blood sample", I'd say it's more accurate to say "take his own blood sample *by himself*" which means that he took the needle and inserted it to his own vein. Isn't it?

Comment: No, we'd say: He did his own blood test. If the thing goes to court for whatever reason, one can imagine: But, Your Honor, the patient performed the test on himself.

Comment: As for me, I understand "*He did his own blood test.*" as if the patient tested his own blood in the lab, while I mean about the sample taking from the vein.

Answer (score 2):

You perform a piece of music or an operation or an autopsy. You perform on stage.

- A blood test **is done**.

**I recommend you have it done [the blood test] tomorrow.**

Also, when you use perform (not for music, for medicine), it is a formal word.

- The doctor performed the operation last night.

For music, it is also rather formal:

- We performed [played] in Seattle last year but not this year.

If a person buys a blood test kit online and it is delivered to him or her, one would say:

**I'd recommend you take your sample tomorrow.**

Comment: Wouldn't *I recommend you have it done tomorrow* suggest they're not the one doing the blood test; rather, they're having someone else do it for them? *Perform* is used with *blood test*, and with other similar tests – see [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+a+blood+test%2Cperform+a+blood+test&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). I think user Jan's answer below is correct, although I'm not sure if I agree with the jargon characterization.

Comment: @userr2684291 Yes, it would. [sigh]That's right. The OP does not know the difference between have x done and a professional performing a test. And, in regular English, we say: to have it done for the person for whom the test is being done. And Jan said: attending a test, which is not even correct English.  A professional (nurse or technician) performs a test on a patient. A patient or person has the test done.

Comment: *The OP said: "then he asked me when to do it, while I think it's better to do/perform it tomorrow". That means: to have it done. When I, as a patient, get a blood test, I do not say perform. I say: have it done. Is that clear now?

Comment: I had the impression they actually meant *their friend* would be the one doing the test ("To 'perform' means, in this case, **to take his own blood sample**"), but I'm not sure anymore. The asker writes in such abstruse fashion as to render any attempt at comprehension futile. I'm throwing in the towel on this one.

Comment: @userr2684291 Perform is still wrong. Take a sample, take one's own sample.

Comment: @Jan Where did I say that my friend will do the test by himself? The nurse took the sample today. And that's what I meant from the beginning.

Comment: @JudiciousAllure, OK I've misread it, so I edited my answer. I suggest that you add in your Q that the nurse is performing the test, because this is the most crucial detail.

Comment: Done. I didn't notice that it wasn't understood. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

In medicine, *perform* typically refers to what a health provider does to a patient. An actor performs when he is in the front of an audience. If your friend orders an online test and the nurse does the test, it is then the nurse who "performs the test" and your friend "has a test."  You usually do not say "perform" when you are doing something for yourself.

So, I would say:

> I recommend you to have it (the test) tomorrow.